# Why is a different zlib window bits value required for extraction, compared with compression?

Tags: c++, c, zlib, compression

I am trying to debug a problem with some code that uses `zlib` 1.2.8. The problem is that this larger project can make archives, but runs into `Z_DATA_ERROR` header problems when trying to extract that archive.

To do this, I wrote a small test program in C++ that compresses ("deflates") a specified regular file, writes the compressed data to a second regular file, and extracts ("inflates") to a third regular file, one line at a time. I then `diff` the first and third files to make sure I get the same bytes.

For reference, this test project is located at: https://github.com/alexpreynolds/zlib-test and compiles under Clang (and should also compile under GNU GCC).

My larger question is how to deal with header data correctly in my larger project.

In my first test scenario, I can set up compression machinery with the following code:

```
z_error = deflateInit(this->z_stream_ptr, ZLIB_TEST_COMPRESSION_LEVEL);
```

Here, `ZLIB_TEST_COMPRESSION_LEVEL` is `1`, to provide best speed. I then run `deflate()` on the `z_stream` pointer until there is nothing left that comes out of compression.

To extract these bytes, I can use `inflateInit()`:

```
int ret = inflateInit(this->z_stream_ptr);
```

So what is the header format, in this case?

In my second test scenario, I set up the deflate machinery like so:

```
z_error = deflateInit2(this->z_stream_ptr, 
                       ZLIB_TEST_COMPRESSION_LEVEL, 
                       ZLIB_TEST_COMPRESSION_METHOD, 
                       ZLIB_TEST_COMPRESSION_WINDOW_BITS,
                       ZLIB_TEST_COMPRESSION_MEM_LEVEL,
                       ZLIB_TEST_COMPRESSION_STRATEGY);
```

These deflate constants are, respectively, `1` for level, `Z_DEFLATED` for method, `15+16` or `31` for window bits, `8` for memory level, and `Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY` for strategy.

The former `inflateInit()` call does not work; instead, I must use `inflateInit2()` and specify a modified window bits value:

```
int ret = inflateInit2(this->z_stream_ptr, ZLIB_TEST_COMPRESSION_WINDOW_BITS + 16);
```

In this case, the window bits value is not `31` as in the `deflateInit2()` call, but `15+32` or `47`.

If I use `31` (or any other value than `47`), then I get a `Z_DATA_ERROR` on subsequent `inflate()` calls. That is, if I use the same window bits for the `inflateInit2()` call:

```
int ret = inflateInit2(this->z_stream_ptr, ZLIB_TEST_COMPRESSION_WINDOW_BITS);
```

Then I get the following error on attempting to `inflate()`:

```
Error: inflate to stream failed [-3]
```

Here, `-3` is the same as `Z_DATA_ERROR`.

According to the documentation, using `31` with `deflateInit2()` should write a `gzip` header and trailer. Thus, `31` on the following `inflateInit2()` call should be expected to be able to extract the header information.

Why is the modified value `47` working, but not `31`?

My test project is mostly similar to the example code on the `zlib` site, with the exception of the extraction/inflation code, which inflates one `z_stream` chunk at a time and parses the output for newline characters.

Is there something special about running `inflate()` only when a new buffer of extracted data is asked for — like header information going missing between `inflate()` calls — as opposed to running the whole extraction in one pass, as in the `zlib` example code?

My larger debugging problem is looking for a robust way to extract a chunk of `zlib`-compressed data only on request, so that I can extract data one line at a time, as opposed to getting the whole extracted file. Something about the way I am handling the `zlib` format parameter seems to be messing me up, but I can't figure out why or how to fix this.

Answer (score 9):

`deflateInit()` and `inflateInit()`, as well as `deflateInit2()` and `inflateInit2()` with `windowBits` in 0..15 all process zlib-wrapped deflate data.  (See [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950) and [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).)

`deflateInit2()` and `inflateInit2()` with negative `windowBits` in -1..-15 process raw deflate data with no header or trailer.  `deflateInit2()` and `inflateInit2()` with `windowBits` in 16..31, i.e. 16 added to 0..15, process gzip-wrapped deflate data ([RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952)).  `inflateInit2()` with `windowBits` in 32..47 (32 added to 0..15) will automatically detect either a gzip or zlib header (but not raw deflate data), and decompress accordingly.

> Why is the modified value 47 working, but not 31?

31 does work.  I did not try to look at your code to debug it.

> Is there something special about running inflate() only when a new
> buffer of extracted data is asked for — like header information going
> missing between inflate() calls — as opposed to running the whole
> extraction in one pass, as in the zlib example code?

I can't figure out what you're asking here.  Perhaps a more explicit example would help.  The whole point of `inflate()` is to decompress a chunk at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately, 31 does not work. All I have to do is tweak that value, recompile and run a second test to confirm.

Comment: Then there is a bug in your program, assuming that you are both compressing and decompressing using 31.

Comment: Unfortunately, other than processing the output buffer differently, which has no connection to compression/extraction routines (or shouldn't, it's just a buffer for bytes), I'm using example code from the `zlib` site that deflate and inflate data, and tweaking window bits to see what setting works and what setting doesn't.

Comment: I'm only citing what the `zlib` documentation says should work.

Comment: If I had some pointers on what exactly to debug, perhaps that would help solve the problem? I am using the `zlib` inflate routine in the same way as described in the documentation.

Comment: There is a myriad of possible bugs that could result in a `Z_DATA_ERROR`.  Just about anything that corrupts the input data, stomps on it, feeding it discontiguous pieces, re-feeding it pieces already fed, feeding it random data, etc.  It may or may not help to check the `msg` member of the stream to see what caused the decoding to fail.  It may also help to look at how much of the input data was consumed when the error was returned.